# android - pass data from one activity to a list in a second activity

Tags: android, list, android-activity

new to droid programming. im having a small problem that im sure is simply fixed but ive done some searching and a bunch of tutorials but cant seem to find just what i need so i figured id ask. My app has 2 activites, the first activity is just a simple form where a user enters course information(class title, professor..etc.)
the first activity passes the data which is supposed to be stored in a list in the second activity. problem is that only the first course gets stored in the list, after the first time nothing new gets added to the second activity. Can someone point me in the right direction please? thanks in advance

First Activity

```
public class CourseDetail extends Activity {

//Course c = new Course();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(onSave);
}

private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText course=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.course);
        EditText professor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.professor);
        EditText location=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.location);
        EditText officehrs=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.officehrs);

        Intent i=new Intent(CourseDetail.this, CourseList.class);
        i.putExtra("myCourse", course.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("myProfessor", professor.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("myLocation", location.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("myOfficehrs", officehrs.getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
};
}
```

Second Activity

```
public class CourseList extends Activity {
Button btnCourse; 
List<Course> model = new ArrayList<Course>();
CourseAdapter adapter=null;
private String dCourse="";
private String dProfessor="";
private String dLocation="";
private String dOfficehrs="";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clist);
    ListView list =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.courses);
    adapter=new CourseAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    Course c = new Course();        
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    dCourse = extras !=null ? extras.getString("myCourse") :"no value entered";
    dProfessor = extras !=null ? extras.getString("myProfessor") :"no value entered";
    dLocation = extras !=null ? extras.getString("myLocation") :"no value entered";
    dOfficehrs = extras !=null ? extras.getString("myOfficehrs") :"no value entered";

    c.setCourse(dCourse);
    c.setProfessor(dProfessor);
    c.setLocation(dLocation);
    c.setOfficeHrs(dOfficehrs);


    btnCourse =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCourse);
    btnCourse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: How did you get to know that only the first course is getting saved?

Comment: running the droid emulator and using the app its obvious very fast

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not adding the newly added items to the List.So before setting adapter you have to add all your objects like

```
 list.add(c);
```

Comment: while attempting to solve it i was moving "adapter.add(c)" around and must have not realized i didnt put it back before posting my code but i do have that line, without that line no courses get added, with it, still one but im trying other answers still

Answer (score 0):

You are just getting the user entered value in CourseDetail activity and displaying the received value inside the CourseList activity, that means you are not storing these values permanently.

Go through this [Android - Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) document.

When you move to 2nd activity i.e. CourseList activity, at that time fetch the data from  the SQLite table and display the same. whenever you get new values from previous activity, at that time just update the list by adding the new data in ArrayList and make a call on **`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`**

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Have your `CourseList` extend `ListActivity` instead of just `Activity` - check out some tutorials on that which should help you set things up correctly.
- There seems to be a bit of confusion with how you're handling your lists - you have your `model` variable but don't seem to be doing anything with it. Again, have a look at a ListView tutorial (just google "android listview tutorial").
- You seem to have figured out that you can use "intents" to pass information from one activity to another, but since you're only doing this in the `onCreate()` method, it's only happening once. Try doing this in your `ListActivity`'s adapter once for each item.

Don't give up on Android, keep trying :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestion:

1. You have to add your object to the adapter:  `adapter.add(c);` after you get the data.
2. Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify the system that your data for the listView has been changed. Call `list.invalidate()` to refresh it.
3. I noticed that you set the button with the `finish()` method. Hmm, if you do so, the next time you get to CourseList Activity from CourseDetail, the adapter will be null again. No previously received data will be available. Is this what you really want?